# Cannot collect data from radiobutton in CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a simple web form in codeigniter but facing a problem with radio button.

I have added two radio button. one is working perfectly, but the other one isn't

This is View:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="wai_banner_photography">Would you like to include photography in your website's banner?</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="includephotography[]" value="yes"/>&nbsp;<label>Yes</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="includephotography[]" value="no" />&nbsp;<label>No</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="wai_provide_stockimage">Would you like us to provide you with suitable stock images?</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="providestockimage[]" value="yes"/>&nbsp;<label>Yes</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="providestockimage[]" value="no"/>&nbsp;<label>No</label><br>
            </div>
```

This is Controller part for collecting data:

```
    $include_photography = $this->input->post('includephotography');
    echo "26 ";
    print_r($include_photography);
    echo "<br/>";

    $pprovidestockimage = $this->input->post('providestockimage');
    echo "27 ";
    print_r($pprovidestockimage);
    echo "<br/>";
```

The output i am getting is:

[image]

I think, i am missing something small. Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Demo: http://forumtest.your365days.com/brief/

Comment: Spelling error? pprovidestockimage two p's

Comment: That's intentional. that variable is to save that data what i am collecting by "$this->input->post('providestockimage');" this providestockimage is the name of the radiobuttons in view. "pprovidestockimage" is just a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons used to return one value so their name must not be an array like this

```
name="includephotography[]"
```

it must be

```
name="includephotography"
```

and after this you must use

```
echo $include_photography;
```

instead of

```
print_r($include_photography);
```

may be this will help

Comment: the includephotography radio button is working without problem. it's the other radio button which is having problem. See the output part. the part started with 26 is ok. but the one with 27 isn't. i did both in the same way.

Comment: try to debug it using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`

Comment: Okay, let me check. by the way, if you want to see the demo, it's uploaded here: http://forumtest.your365days.com/brief/

Comment: Hi, Getting

26 array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "yes" } 
27 bool(false)

after using var_dump. it seems the radiobutton is not passing any data.

Comment: there is a changed name on your form which is `photoprovidebyus` at your form in the demo please check that

Comment: Thanks a lot. i changed files from two different directories.

Answer (score 0):

Radio button willl post value only if any one of them is selected.

You might have selected radio button in first case but not in second case.

Comment: No, i did. i checked that.

Comment: though i am selecting, but it seems no data is passing. what can cause this problem?